# How to execute code from string Rails and render it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `content` column in my `Posts` table. I insert into `Posts` table some info in Post model

```
Post.create({content: "<%= link_to('post', post_path) %> blah blah ... "})
```

When I want to renter `@post.content` I receive `"<%= link_to('post', post_path) %> blah blah ..."` without string executing.

How to render it right?

Comment: You do what you want off course :) but I have to tell you that storing executable code in your database is not a good idea in the long term

Comment: As Benjamin said, it's a bad idea, short and long term. Frankly I'm not even sure how you would accomplish this anyways. It might work if you ditched the outer ERB brackets and used `eval` on the string. However, if your intention is to render something that is specific to only one or a few objects, it would be far better and easier to build this in to the model, or view template itself.

Comment: @user1538633 why not store string in a text column instead of code?

Comment: I know that its bad idea. Actually I have to write something like "post analyzer" that would cover @usernames and #hashtags by links. I recognise 2 ways how to do it. First way is executing "post analyzer" each time while user requests posts or second is store analyzed posts. Which way is better or you know third way? thank you all.

Comment: @user1538633 I can't quote any best practice sources but I would argue that you should process content on request, not on save. That way, you can change the behaviour, or add new functionality to this post analyzer, without worrying about updating the previously analyzed post content.

Comment: This answer gives a clear explanation of the reason why it is a bad design: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653201/storing-code-in-an-sql-database-and-executing-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as said it is a very wrong idea to store code in your database. There is very little exception to that and it's very complicated to implement, bug prone, and present security issues. In short: don't do it.

So you need an alternative design. There is basically 3 situations, pick-up the one that correspond to your application's goal:

**A-** If your method parameters and output will never change in the future, then you execute your code and store the output in a cached columns (type string or text) of your model before saving. When retrieving this cached output later you can just use it as it

```
post.cached_output = my_method(...)
post.save
# In the future, in your view:
<%= post.cached_output %>
```

**B-** If the parameter of your method will never change in the future but the method output differs according to external elements, then just store that one parameter's value and call the method each time you need its output

```
post.cached_parameter = 17
post.save
# In the future, in your view:
<%= my_method(params: post.cached_parameter) %>
```

**C-** If your method's parameter change over time and your method output also changes overtime, then you don't need to cache anything in your database