# Python convert string to function and execute it

Tags: python, string, function, exec

I have several functions in the database as a strings and there is a main function that should take these functions from the database and execute them as functions, and not as text.

How I can transform a string (which describes a function) into a function with arguments and execute it in Python?

*I'm tried exec but I can't return something from function and use it.*

For example my function:

```
some_function = """
def my_random_function(some_param):
    print(some_param)
    return time.time()
"""
```

Comment: Hey, @Nataly Firstova, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719466/i-have-a-string-whose-content-is-a-function-name-how-to-refer-to-the-correspond

Comment: Function defined by `exec` can work like normal function, and of course you can also get the return values. Make sure you have import all the essential libraries (`time` in your example).
PS: I will post some code for you in answer

Answer (score 3):

100% Never do this ever under any circumstances disclaimer...

the `exec` statement:

```
code = """
def f(x):
    x = x + 1
    return x

print('This is my output.')
print(f(my_var))
"""

exec(code, {}, {"my_var": 1})
```

output:

```
This is my output.
2
```

Comment: 100% Never do this ever under any circumstances disclaimer... - why? I just want to put all functions in DB, and change it without server reload

Comment: It is very insecure and unreliable. See here for someone wanting to do this in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14653229/6014330

Comment: Maybe you know better way for it? I want to add end edit my functions in DB (via frontend editor) and execute it in main function on server (without redeploy)

Comment: That's exactly the problem. what you want to do is inherently dangerous. Its like asking to log into your bank account without a username and password. You cant do it securely.

Comment: The whole point of CI/CD is so that you can make changes, test them, validate it etc then promote to an environment and test again... You should not be able to change code on the fly without a deployment.

Comment: But how FaaS services like amazon lambda works? I can write python function in web interface and execute it.

Comment: Lambda stores code in an encrypted S3 bucket. Amazon is also worth $46 billion and have a few thousand security engineers making sure its all secure.

Comment: I mean functionally, how it works for them, how text from a web-editor turns into a python function

Comment: There will be cases we need to run code from the front end. Amazon Lambda is an example, and another example is an online IDE. But make sure that the code will not threaten your server, or more clearly will not change how your server works. For example, Amazon Lambda will isolate your code and run it on some virtual environment rather than run directly inside Amazon Lambda code.

Answer (score 0):

Function defined by `exec` can work like normal function, and of course you can also get the return values. Make sure you have import all the essential libraries (`time` in your example)

```py
import time

some_function = """
def my_random_function(some_param):
    print(some_param)
    return time.time()
"""

exec(some_function)
return_value = my_random_function(3)
print(return_value)
```

output

```
3
1637328869.3345668
```

Comment: I got IDE error on it return_value = my_random_function(3)

Comment: What is the error? Can you provide what the error said?

Comment: Unresolved reference "my_random_function"

Comment: I guess you are using Pycharm. It is the Pycharm error since Pycharm needs to know where to find a function, and it can not find a function inside a string. Python can run it smoothly because the function will appear after the `exec` run.